# ¿Como formar secuencias unicode dinamicamente?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

tengo entendido que ahora en  `javascript`, es posible usar secuencias `unicode` literales, es decir `\u09A1` por ejemplo, sin embargo ¿Es posible "formar" una secuencia usando variables?

Algo como:

```
var unicode = "09A1";
var char = "\u" + unicode;
```

¿Es eso posible?

Comment: No, te dará una exception `Invalid Unicode escape sequence` ya que requiere una serie de caracteres despues del escape [Javascript Escapes](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes#unicode). Pero puedes hacer `var char = "0x" + unicode;` y despues `String.fromCodePoint(char);`

Comment: Otra forma de hacer lo mismo sería `String.fromCodePoint(parseInt(unicode,16))`

Comment: Justamente lo que necesito!

Comment: @PabloLozano por qué la respuesta quedó en un comentario y no en una respuesta? :O